# How to reflect xib file’s constraints in my Table View?

Tags: swift, cell, xib

I’m so stuck with creating various cell types in my Table View.

This is my way to do it.

1. Create a TableView and put a prototype cell and give it a identifier(let’s say “cell1” here)
2. Create a TableViewCell file with xib file and give them the same identifier as I gave to the prototype cell(“cell1”)
3. In the xib file, I put one imageView and label to the cell. Then set some constrains to them. Also connected them to the TableView cell file as outlets.
4. In the TableViewCell file, I added those two imageView and label as subview to self.
5. In the TableViewController file, I registered the Nib.
6. In the TableViewController file, I set a text to the label I created in the xib file(in the “cellForRowAt” method)

I created a custom cell file with xib file and set a imageView and Label to the cell in the xib file. Then I gave an sample image to the image View and set some constrains to the imageView and label.

And then I registered my Nib into my TableViewComtroller file in View did load method.

Finally, the custom cell I created in my xib file appears on my TableView BUT the constrains I set up in the xib file completely disappears. It seems like the imageView and label are located kind of randomly. And also the sample image I set up for the imageView doesn’t appear neither.

Could someone possibly help me out please?

Comment: Do issue is resolved ?

Comment: Hi, iOS Geek. Thank you for comment! I actually couldn't find the solution so I put several cells in storyboard and give them custom cell file each(without xib file)!

Comment: Okay , So its solved by your en ? if yes, you can close this thread

Comment: yep! thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you had not provided any screenshot I can refer you a reference here with this link I had used TableView With sections in which Header cell is From Xib

I didn't faced such issue about my Constraints You can check this file as reference and hope you get where you are mistaking , if still you find issue please Comment

https://github.com/RockinGarg/Expandable-TableView-.git